# Laravel - Iterating pivot data (Property does not exist on this collection instance)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a many-to-many relationship between `Order` and `Product`

`Product.php`

```
public function orders()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class)
                ->withTimestamps()
                ->withPivot('qty');
}
```

`Order.php`

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)
                ->withTimestamps()
                ->withPivot('qty');
}
```

Now whenever I try to utilize an iteration in a view (in this case I am just trying to show the form which iterates through all available `Product`s, I always receive the error...

```
Property [products] does not exist on this collection instance.
```

`create.blade.php`

```
@foreach ($products->orders as $product)

# Order inputs are here

{{ Form::text('qty', $product->pivot->qty, [
                          'type' => 'tel',
                            'min' => 0,
                            'max' => 20,
                            'step' => 1,
                            'placeholder' => '0',
                            'class' => 'meal'
                            ]) }}
@endforeach
```

I have also attempted `@foreach ($products->orders as $product)` and both approaches give me that same error.

I have attempted many different ways in my Controller to fix this error, here is my last attempt:

`OrderControlller.php`

```
public function create()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $products = Product::get();
    $orders = $user->orders;

    return view('orders.create', compact('products', 'orders', 'user'));
}
```

**UPDATE**

@alan's answer is correct, I am sure, however...

I am still getting "Property [pivot] does not exist on this collection instance" whenever I try to run an iteration.

The concept of an iteration inside of an iteration in this instance is confusing for me.

I cannot visualize how Laravel is handling the pivot connection. In tinker when I load up just the Product table, there is no `qty` column. (This makes sense because that is on the pivot table). This also explains this new error.

Should I be doing something in the vein of this? :

changed `create.blade.php`

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
 {{ Form::text('qty', $product->orders->pivot->qty }}
```

OrderController.php

```
$user = Auth::user();
$orders = $user->orders;
$products= []; #pass products to view as an array
$p = $orders->products; #this relationship brings in pivot data? 
foreach ($p as $orders) {
   #would I then somehow pass just this qty here?
}
```

Problem is I am always getting a "Property does not exist" error, be it with 'products', 'orders', or 'pivot'.

Comment: Looks like $products is a collection, the orders is defined as a relationship on an individual Product. You need to first iterate through the products. Then you should be able to access an individual product's orders from it.

Comment: @Alan, I think I am understanding the error now. There is no 'orders' in that collection because I am defining '$products' as only the data from the products table. (I am not making any association currently that brings in the pivot data)


So the "->orders" create sort of a one-to-one relationship that can be iterated through only if I am working within a larger iteration which brings in that pivot data?


There is some concept eluding me here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. You were trying to access the orders property on the $products variable, which is a Laravel Collection (get method on model returns a collection). So instead of doing that you just iterate through the products and access the pivot table from the individual product model.

```
@foreach ($products as $product)

# Order inputs are here

{{ Form::text('qty', $product->orders->pivot->qty, [
                          'type' => 'tel',
                            'min' => 0,
                            'max' => 20,
                            'step' => 1,
                            'placeholder' => '0',
                            'class' => 'meal'
                            ]) }}
@endforeach
```

**Update:**
Actually that makes sense. A record on the pivot table defines an association between an order and a product. So for you to access a record in the pivot table you must access the product or order from its relationship. This is what I would do.

OrderController.php

```
$user = Auth::user();
$user->load("orders.products"); // eager load relationship to avoid N+1 problem
$orders = $user->orders;
return view('orders.create', compact('orders', 'user'));
```

create.blade.php

```
@foreach ($orders as $order)
    @foreach ($order->products as $product)


    {{ Form::text('qty', $product->pivot->qty, [
                          'type' => 'tel',
                            'min' => 0,
                            'max' => 20,
                            'step' => 1,
                            'placeholder' => '0',
                            'class' => 'meal'
                            ]) }}
     @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Some resources:

[Eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

[Many to Many relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Comment: I seem to still be missing something in my attempts at making this new iteration. I have updated the question regarding this.

Comment: Ok that makes way more sense now. Thank you.